# SQL Grouping with null rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I've searched around a bit and couldn't find anything that addressed my exact issue

I have a table (MSSQL), and the data looks like this:

```
Source table:

RID    FullName FirstName   LastName    Email               Address
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      NULL     [BOB]       NULL        NULL                NULL
1      NULL     NULL        [BOB]       NULL                NULL
1      NULL     NULL        NULL        [bob@bob.com]       NULL
2      NULL     [JAY]       NULL        NULL                NULL
2      NULL     NULL        [JAY]       NULL                NULL
2      NULL     NULL        NULL        [jerry@jerry.com]   NULL
3      NULL     [RICK]      NULL        NULL                NULL
3      NULL     NULL        [RICK]      NULL                NULL
3      NULL     NULL        NULL        [rick@rick.com]     NULL
```

But I need to transform the data to look like this:

```
Results table:

RID     FullName             Email                Address
---------------------------------------------------------
1       [BOB] [BOB]        [bob@bob.com]          NULL
2       [JAY] [JAY]        [jerry@jerry.com]      NULL
3       [RICK] [RICK]      [rick@rick.com]        NULL
```

**NOTE:**  If Fullname from the source table is NULL, then we combine FirstName and LastName.  (If both FirstName and LastName are NULL, then we simply have a NULL FullName result, which is completely fine).

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `group by`:

```
select rid, coalesce(max(FullName), max(FirstName)+' '+max(LastName)) as FullName,
       max(Email) as Email,
       max(Address) as Address
from t
group by rid
order by 1
```

Comment: I had tried this already, but was missing the aggregate functions on Name/Email/Address.  Can you tell me why they're needed?  This correctly answers my question (will mark as answer once SO lets me). Thanks!

Comment: Just curious - why the `order by 1`?

Comment: Never-mind, I believe I understand the need for the MAX() aggregates now.  Thanks again.

Comment: `order by 1` is the same as `order by rid`. You can specify the ordinal position of the column you want to sort on, specially usefull when using aggregate on a field!

Comment: By the way, your answer is not 100% correct. You should add a ISNULL on the MAX(FIRSTNAME) and MAX(LASTNAME), otherwise concatening `NULL + ' ' + 'BOB'` will result in NULL in the case someone has no FIRSTNAME or LASTNAME in the table.

Comment: @DominicGoulet . . . The question doesn't actually specify what to do if only one of the names is NULL.  My version happens to yield NULL rather than choosing one of the names.  Either way is equally correct, since that case is not considered in the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff We do actually understand requirements differently! ;-) But that's not a problem right now. As 'combine' is not a SQL statement, I read it functionnally. Nulling a concatenation because one side is NULL is really technical. He also specified a functionnal case if both are NULLs, which sounds to me he never intended to NULL the result if only one side is NULL. But your answer is still the right one. IMO, we should have a `COALSECE(MAX(FIRSTNAME) + ' ' + MAX(LASTNAME), MAX(FIRSTNAME), MAX(LASTNAME))`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way, although a bit convoluted. I do not know your full data set, but *this should give you all possible combinations in case you have multiple entries for each RID* (e.g. multiple rows with different FirstName values).

```
SELECT a.RID, b.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS FullName, d.Email
FROM myTable a
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable b ON a.RID = b.RID AND b.FirstName IS NOT NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable c ON a.RID = c.RID AND c.LastName IS NOT NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable d ON a.RID = d.RID AND d.Email IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.RID, b.FirstName, c.LastName, d.Email
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77802/1)